# Are there technical benefits between Cornerstone vs. Xcode 4.5's built-in SVN?

Tags: xcode, svn, version-control, cornerstone

I've been a user of Zennaware's Cornerstone 2 for a while now and am really happy with it.  However, I'm about to start a new project, and with Xcode 4, Apple re-wrote their built-in SVN client (and also added GIT) so I'm considering switching.

Now I know not to ask 'which do you prefer and why' type questions (like this: [Cornerstone vs Versions for Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426811/cornerstone-vs-versions-for-mac-os-x)) since they are subjective and thus are most likely to be closed, but I'm asking from a technical perspective, not a user preference perspective, are there limitations or benefits to one over the other?

For instance, while the side-by-side version review in Xcode seems like it's a very useful feature being able to 'scrub' through your history, that is a preference/feature kind of thing.  However, I have read that the built-in SVN client has trouble with externals (this may have been a pre-4.x version... they didn't say), which is a technical limitation that may make the built-in source control unusable for our needs regardless of usability.

That said, are there any known limitations, missing features, benefits, drawbacks from a technical perspective (i.e. repository version supported, etc.) of using one over the other?  Built-in sounds appealing, but I don't want to commit only to hit a compatibility wall, or worse, corruption.